# 3ds max - selected object screen shot

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, 3ds

How would I take a screen shot of a few objects from the top view excluding the background and other objects.

Is it possible??

If it isn't, then how do I make the background and grid invisible or transparent so that I can output an image with only my selected object.

Comment: Are you talking about using MaxScript for this? Otherwise, this seems off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: Script would be next, but I don't know how I would do it using the UI.

Comment: I don't see any "maxscript" category, so no this is not off topic.
it's a genuine 3dsmax question.

If you need help with the script, just let us know.

Answer (score 1):

With no script, you have to :

1. press 'G' for hiding grid in current
   selected viewport.
2. select your objects
3. right-click and select "hide unselected".
4. zoom extent by pressing "z"
5. go to "tools->Grab viewport". (max 2011).

This can be done with script fairly easily.

Comment: This is not actually accurate - you say "G" hides the grid but in fact it toggles it. This makes it invalid for script use as you need a method to actually request the current display state of the grid, eg. whether it's currently visible. There doesn't appear to be a script method available to do this.